# How to deal with multiple new lines until an empty line is reached in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

Let's consider !

```
const str = `
    Get between @
          Yes me.

    Get between @
          Me, Me.
          Yes.

`
```

A function named **parse()** can do something like this :

```
console.log( parse( str ) )
```

Output :

```
Get between this.
Get between this.
```

So, you might be confused, what am I saying ? So, I am clearing that out. You can see that the **parse()** replaced the content between the **@** and an empty line with **this.**. So, how can I make the function. Here's my try :

```js
const str = `
    Get between @
          Yes me.

    Get between @
          Me, Me.
          Yes.

`;

const parse = (val) => {
    val = val.replace(
    /\b@\b([\S\s]*?)\n/gm, "this." 
     )
    return val
};

console.log(parse(str));
```

But it's not working as I wished it to do. I know I have put `\n` in the last, which will catch up the very first new line, but I am not understanding how to deal with multiple newlines after which the emptyline lies. So can you help me to make my function better ?

Comment: First remove the word boundaries around `@`.

Comment: I'm still confused by all the me yes me me... What should your string parser do actually? Is the *`"Get between"`* string a static value? Something you can use as anchor?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this might work for you, but I would consider getting only the lines that end in `@`, and than iterate the matches with a replace:

```js
const str = `
    Get between @
          Yes me.

    Get some @
          Me, Me.
          Yes.

`;

const parse = str => str.match(/(?!\s+).+@/g).map(m => m.replace('@', 'this.')).join('\n');

console.log(parse(str))
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also match for the string before the `@` and then replace `@` by `this` and `\n`

```js
const str = `
    Get between @
          Yes me.

    Get between @
          Me, Me.
          Yes.

`
const parse = (val) => {
    val = val.match(
     /\w.*@/g).join().replace(/(@,)|@/g, 'this.\n')
    return val
}

console.log(parse(str))
```